# Run Speed in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, cpu-speed

I have written an slow code and want to make it faster. I think the must time consumer part is below part which called a function (F_xy). Is there a simple way to make the code faster for this part?
(Length(t) is approximately 1000000.)

```
 for i=1:(length(t)-1)                              % calculation loop
k_1 = F_xy(t(i),xx(i),aa,bb,l,T,K,F,D,del); 
k_2 = F_xy(t(i)+0.5*h,xx(i)+0.5*h*k_1,aa,bb,l,T,K,F,D,del);
k_3 = F_xy((t(i)+0.5*h),(xx(i)+0.5*h*k_2),aa,bb,l,T,K,F,D,del);
k_4 = F_xy((t(i)+h),(xx(i)+k_3*h),aa,bb,l,T,K,F,D,del);
xx(i+1) = xx(i) + (1/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4)*h;    % main equation
`end`
```

function is as below:

```
function Fp = F_xy(t,r,aa,bb,l,T,K,F,D,del)
W_0 = @(r) aa * ( sin(2*pi*r/l) + (del/4)*sin(4*pi*r/l)) + bb;
WW_0 = @(r) (2 * pi * aa / l) *( cos(2*pi*r/l) + (del/2) *cos(4*pi*r/l) );
ff = @(r) -D / (K * T * sqrt(1 + WW_0(r)*WW_0(r)));
ss = @(r) - T * K * (WW_0(r)/W_0(r));
index = round(t);
if(index > 0 && index <= length(F))
 Fp = ff(r)*(F(index) + ss(r));]
else
error('index out of bounds');
end
end
```

Comment: Without knowing the structure of `F_xy`, I don't think we can help you.  Time marches aren't vectorizable.

Comment: I added the function

Comment: You will improve performance by not making those anonymous functions every call.  Just calculate and use them as normal arrays.